# Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource works with Java 6, fails with Java 7

Tags: java, spring, servlets, internationalization, java-7

Our declaration:

```xml
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
     <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                    <value>WEB-INF/classes/caasMessages</value>
            </list>
     </property>
     <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
     <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

We've tried classpath:caasMessages, we've tried just caasMessages. The actual files are in WEB-INF/classes and include caasMessages.properties, caasMessages_es.properties and so on.

The error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'screen.confirmLoginStats.title' for locale 'en_US'.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.jsp.ssn.casLoginView_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(casLoginView_jsp.java:403)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.jsp.ssn.casLoginView_jsp._jspService(casLoginView_jsp.java:105)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

And so on.

We're really, really, REALLY sure that message is in caasMessages.properties. And, as I said in the title, this works fine when Tomcat is run under JDK6, but fails under JDK7 as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Java 6 versus Java 7 was a red herring. A "hidden" context file was defining a second messageSource incorrectly. For unknown reasons, the correct bean was preferred with Java 6 and the incorrect one with Java 7.